# Sharepoint non-site setting to always show ribbon?

Tags: ribbon, sharepoint-2013

Our office is slowly shifting sites to 2013 from 2010. It seems they're setting the site settings such that the ribbon is hidden, but expandable, by default. Is there a way I can tell Sharepoint *I* would like to always see the ribbon? In other words, I'm curious if there is a setting associated to my account that I can toggle such that the ribbon always displays (assuming I'm allowed to see it at all in the given site), despite what the individual site setting is.

Comment: Isn't it a matter of hovering the ribbon, and then press a tack in the bottom right corner to pin it?

Comment: I'm not seeing a tack when I expand the ribbon manually. Also, if there were such a tack, wouldn't that only be for the one site? Better than nothing I'll grant, but I'm hoping there's something more global.

Comment: Hmm, I'll need a bit more to work with then. Can you provide a screenshot of what you see when the ribbon is visible?